# Bubble-Sort: Ascending Lists v/s Descending Lists

Tags: bubble-sort, sorting

> L1 = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
>   L2 = [8, 1, 3, 6, 9, 7, 4, 2, 5]

Would `L1` cause bubblesort to do more swaps since the elements are in non-ascending order? I don't really understand what determines bubblesort to do more/less swaps.

Comment: Homework? Do it yourself. You could even write code to count the comparisons.

Comment: Why don't you run it (either on a computer, or on paper), and find out?

Comment: One way to determine which inputs did the most swaps would be to code up the bubble sort algorithm and then simply count the number of times a swap occurred. At the end of bubble sort you could print out this number and use it to compare different inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, L2 would make Bubble-sort do more swaps. Bubble-sort is seriously slowed down by `turtles` (i.e., small numbers near the end of the list). `Rabbits` (i.e., large numbers near the beginning of the code) get swapped quickly and don't matter while turtles move forward in the list slowly, once w/ every iteration.

That's why you almost never never use bubblesort in any heavy-duty sorting code. [Introsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort) and [Cocktail Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocktail_sort) are better variations of bubble-sort.

I don't get why you're asking this question here, and why you've tagged this question w/ `python` (though that *is* the only reason I saw this question in the first place).

Comment: @alicew, just fixed a major mistake (confused `rabbits` w/ `turtles`), and added more stuff.